# Fade out and fade in with a new image in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, fade, qwidget

I'm new wit Qt.
When I start my application I'll fade out a white image and then my startMenu widget which contains some QPushbutton should show up.

```
StartMenu::StartMenu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::StartMenu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);//hide frame window
    ui->centralwidget->setStyleSheet("image: url(:/gui.png);");


    QGraphicsOpacityEffect *opacityEffect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
    opacityEffect->setOpacity(1.0);
    ui->centralwidget->setGraphicsEffect(opacityEffect);
    QPropertyAnimation * anim = new QPropertyAnimation(this);
    anim->setTargetObject(opacityEffect);
    anim->setPropertyName("opacity");
    anim->setDuration(4000);
    anim->setStartValue(opacityEffect->opacity());
    anim->setEndValue(0);
    anim->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutQuad);
    anim->start(QAbstractAnimation::KeepWhenStopped);
}
```

So far i have written this code, but this code fade out the whole centralwidget. Hope you guys understand my question and can help me.

Comment: You set the graphics effect on the centralWidget, which is why the animation is applied to that.

Comment: Hello @Merlin069. i'm aware of that. But how can it only be an image fading away and the show the now fading widget.